# Trying to group a tree exported from command prompt

Tags: grouping, unique-values

In excel macro, i am trying to get numbers to group as follows.

1
1
2
2
5
5
5
1
1
7
7
7
7
1
1
 My data is in the format above. I need the numbers that are next too each other need to group.

For example 
1 Grouped
2 Grouped
5 Grouped
1 Grouped
7 Grouped
1 Grouped

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

### Grouping data in Excel has many straightforward options

- Grouping in excel is available:

  - based on the "outline" feature
  - based on the "grouping" feature
  - based on the "pivot table" feature

#### See also

- [MSFT Excel Support -- Pivot tables](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-A9A84538-BFE9-40A9-A8E9-F99134456576)